# Postgres 9.5 table replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to replicate few tables from one server to another using foreign data wrappers and creating materialized views on foreign tables but it's not real time. How can I replicate it real time, upgrading or other replication tools is not an option.

Comment: You could try using trigger function https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: I use `postgres_fdw` for this matter and the foreign table is afaic up to date. Are you experiencing anything else? Remember that materialized views need to be refreshed __manually__: e.g. `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW viewname`

Comment: If that feature is so important, then upgrading to Postgres 10 and using logical replication is the only sensible solution. Everything else would be an ugly workaround.

Comment: tried creating trigger on foreign table but only when i insert in foreign table it writes to another table, I can't upgrade to 10. Refreshing materialized view is taking time to bring in new data, but requirement is real time.

Comment: a trigger will only fire on an event before or after and it can be for insert, update and delete, what are you expecting? Like horse said, if you want real time replication you need to use a replication approach.